# Permanently disable error reports on Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Edition

Tags: ubuntu-touch, privacy

I just received my Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Edition yesterday and I'm having trouble with the privacy settings. When I disable the error reports (check don't send reports in the system settings) they are disabled for up to an hour but then the error reports are enabled again automatically when I check it in the systems settings. Is there a way to fix that so I can be sure that there's definitely no data send to Canonical?

Comment: This appears to be a bug, I've reproduced it here and filed a bug for you. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-system-settings/+bug/1437633

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved with the release of OTA-7.
Disabling error reports now works permanently.